# DOMPDF page break

Tags: css, pdf-generation, dompdf

I'm trying to generate reports with header, footer and content. The header and the footer works fine, however the text of the content div breaks higher than I want. [See the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkmBW.png). I really don't understand why the page is breaking so high.

This is the CSS code:

```css
@page { 
  margin: 180px 50px; 
}

#header { 
  position: fixed; 
  left: 0px; 
  top: -150px; 
  right: 0px; 
  height: 150px; 
  text-align: left; 
}

#footer { 
  position: fixed; 
  left: 0px; 
  bottom: -180px; 
  right: 0px; 
  height: 80px; 
  text-align: right; 
  background-color: lightblue 
}

#footer .page:after { 
  content: counter(page, upper-roman); 
}

#content { 
  padding-left: 10mm; 
  padding-right: 5mm; 
  line-height: 6mm; 
  background-color: lightgreen; 
  height: 850px;
}
#logo { 
  height: 4cm; 
}
#head_text { 
  display: inline-block; 
  line-height: 6mm; 
  padding-top: 15px; 
}
```

And this is the HTML:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      '.$css.'
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="header">
      '.$header.'
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
      <p class="page">Página </p>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
      '.$content.'
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Could anyone help to solve this problem? Tanks!

Comment: Can you give html? And try to change height: auto in #content

Comment: I changed the height to auto and doesn't make difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your DOMPDF_DPI is set to 72 then a 180px margin is pretty expansive. A DPI of 72 gives a one-to-one translation from PX to PT (the native unit in a PDF). PDF documents produced by dompdf are always 72 PPI. That translates into 2.5 inches of margin around the content. I don't think you meant to pad your margins quite that much.

Another problem I see is that you've set a height condition on your content element. You don't really need this and I see it causing some problems as I run some test renders. If you want your content background to have a specific color then I'd recommend setting it on the body element, which is the true bounds of your document content.

Try the following:

```css
@page { 
  margin: 180px 50px; 
}
#header { 
  position: fixed; 
  left: 0px; 
  top: -150px; 
  right: 0px; 
  height: 150px; 
  text-align: left; 
}

#footer { 
  position: fixed; 
  left: 0px; 
  bottom: -180px; 
  right: 0px; 
  height: 80px; 
  text-align: right; 
  background-color: lightblue 
}

#footer .page:after { 
  content: counter(page, upper-roman); 
}

body { 
  background-color: lightgreen; 
  height: 850px;
}
#content {
  padding-left: 10mm; 
  padding-right: 5mm; 
  line-height: 6mm; 
}
#logo { 
  height: 4cm; 
}
#head_text { 
  display: inline-block; 
  line-height: 6mm; 
  padding-top: 15px; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="header">
    HEADER
  </div>

  <div id="footer">
    <p class="page">Página </p>
  </div>

  <div id="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus id erat blandit, auctor massa eu, aliquam lacus. Suspendisse justo ante, gravida vel diam quis, porta luctus nisi. Donec id enim sem. Sed et lobortis magna. Ut et dignissim augue. Cras quam libero, feugiat ac auctor eget, semper a augue. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Suspendisse quis hendrerit ex. Phasellus auctor dolor sit amet nibh rhoncus sagittis. Sed quis odio sit amet purus feugiat malesuada.</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi BrianS, thanks for your help. I tried your suggestion but did not work. The same problem is happening. I am using the height condition to try to avoid the text to break before the place where I want that he breaks. But that don't make difference. With or without the higher condition the same problem happens. I really don't understand why the text is breaking so high on the page.

Comment: The background color is just to show that the text, for some reason that I cannot understand, doesn't occupy the whole div 'content'.

Comment: Regardless of the height of your div dompdf will page break at the bounds of the page. The text is breaking so high because of your page margins. Make those smaller to have the text break lower on the page. If you want to see the page boundaries you can add a border to the body element.

Comment: Oh my god! I'm so idiot, it's so obvious. Thank you very much my friend, this really helped me.